# get path without file name from saveFileDialog?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am try to get my path from `SaveFileDialog` without my file name in order to create a `DirectoryInfo` object

```
private void btnBrowseCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialogBrowse2 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialogBrowse2.Filter = "Pcap file|*.pcap";
    saveFileDialogBrowse2.Title = "Save an pcap File";
    saveFileDialogBrowse2.ShowDialog();

    if (saveFileDialogBrowse2.FileName != "")
    {
        string str = saveFileDialogBrowse2.FileName;

    }
}
```

Comment: You should wrap your `SaveFileDialog` in a `using` statement and test for `saveFileDialogBrowse2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK` instead of the empty filename.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use [`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) for this purpose

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [System.IO.FileInfo.DirectoryName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.directoryname.aspx) property to get the full path of the directory of a file.

---

```
string fileName = @"C:\TMP\log.txt";
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.DirectoryName); // Output: "C:\TMP"
```

---

Using your example:

```
string str = saveFileDialogBrowse2.FileName;

FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(str);
Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.DirectoryName);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string fileName = @"C:\TMP\log.txt";
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.DirectoryName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx) method:

```
Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Filename));
```